# Specialfolder resolutions in differing versions of Windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, special-folders

My project includes a template that is installed in the 32 bit Program Files directory. Accessing this template is relatively simple:

```
string templateLoc = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) 
                                                                            + @"\path.html";
```

This works as intended on my local system, including after building the WiX installer. However, on my client's system, it looks for the template in the System32 directory.

The only real difference between our systems is that I run Windows 7, and my client runs Windows 10. Is there a difference between these systems that affects `Environment`? Or, is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You might want to add to your question the bit-ness (32/64) of the operating systems in question and the specific directory names on each of the machines.

Comment: @STLDeveloper On a modern operating system, what does that have to do with things? I was under the impression that `ProgramFilesX86` returned the `Program Files (x86)` folder on any Windows OS post-vista?